# Sum occurrences using multiple columns in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I am trying to view table results of the total number of accounts that received a certain error message on a particular date. But there are hundreds of different error messages that one account might receive on any given day. For example, this table is called ERROR and my columns are:

```
     date        error     acct#     freq  
2016-04-20       panda       2        1
2016-04-20         pig       2        1
2016-04-20       panda       3        1
2016-04-20       panda       7        1
2016-04-25       panda       4        1
2016-04-27        bird       4        1
2016-04-27        bird       3        1
```

Here is my code:

```
Error_Freq = ddply(ERROR, .(date), summarize, freq=sum(freq))
View(Error_Freq)
```

But this only gives me the total # of accounts per day. 
I want the output to look like:

```
     date        error     freq 
2016-04-20       panda       3
2016-04-20         pig       1
2016-04-25       panda       1
2016-04-27        bird       2
```

Is there another way I should be looking at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `error` also as grouping variable

```
library(dplyr) 
df1 %>% 
   group_by(date, error) %>% 
   summarise(freq = sum(freq))
     date error  freq
#        <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 2016-04-20 panda     3
#2 2016-04-20   pig     1
#3 2016-04-25 panda     1
#4 2016-04-27  bird     2
```

or using `ddply`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df1, .(date, error), summarize, freq=sum(freq))
```